# Visual Studio Windows Phone Application Analysis absolute values needed

Tags: performance, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to perform a performance analysis for some Windows Phone applications. For my analysis, I would like to have the exact values of both the cpu and memory consumption. As far as I know, this is impossible in The Windows Phone Application Analysis tool.

Is there any way to retrieve the actual values in stead of just a graph? I tried to open the logfiles of the tool, but these where unreadable.

Also, is there any other working tools available to measure performance related parameters in Windows Phone applications?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, use the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/releases/view/109917) and use the  control to display the current memory use and peak memory while developing your app.
So download the Toolkit and add the correct dlls to your project. You can also use NuGet.

Now you can add this to your layout:

```
<coding4fun:MemoryCounter 
    xmlns:coding4fun="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls"/>
```

Or declare it in C#:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MemoryCounter counter = new MemoryCounter();
    this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(counter);
}
```

Now you should see two numbers on the top of your screen when you launch it.

[image]

You can see the MemoryCounter results only in DEBUG mode!

Otherwise check the DeviceStatus class out, it has some useful things in it:

```
namespace Microsoft.Phone.Info
{
    public static class DeviceStatus
    {
        public static long ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage { get; } 
        public static long ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage { get; }
        public static long ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit { get; }
        public static long DeviceTotalMemory { get; }
    }
}
```

To see how to use it check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394037(v=vs.105).aspx) out!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply! I will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Windows Phone Power Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629632.aspx). Still doesn't not give you absolute values but shows accurate peak CPU in the graph and other performance characteristics

Comment: I've been looking at this too, but when trying to install it, I get some weird error telling me that I'm missing Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity 12.0.0.0, and I can't seem to find a working solution for this.

Comment: This only works on Windows Phone 8.1 phone. Are you trying on a Windows 10 device?

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Windows Phone Application Analysis -> App Analysis", Summary page gives "Max memory used" and "Average memory used".

To findout out CPU usage, select time range, In details view breadcrumb control select "Performance Warnings -> CPU Usage" and that gives CPU Time (ms) and CPU Time (%) per thread. 
Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215907(v=vs.105).aspx

Does this helps. - pankajsa (MSFT)